# ¿Script para cerrar sesión de los usuarios desconectados en Windows server?

Tags: cmd, sesiones, windows-server, licencias

Les comparto el código para cerrar sesión de usuarios desconectados del Windows server, este código lo pueden colocar en una tarea repetitiva en Windows para que se ejecute cada hora o 30 minutos, las ventajas son: para liberar recursos del servidor y licencias de software.

Si alguien tiene algo mejor lo pueden publicar.

Comment: Por qué tu título dice solucionado?

Comment: Si esto era una pregunta respuesta, la solución va abajo en la zona de respuestas por favor corrige

Comment: porque no encontre ninguna pregunta relacionada con este problema y decidi compartir porque tampoco había encontrado la solución de cerrar la sesión de un usuario conectado en windows server automáticamente. esta solución ha sido aplicada en una empresa donde muchos usuarios se conecta y no cierran sesión y lo que causa es que se consuma los recursos del sistema vanamente y las licencias de algunos programas.

Comment: Entonces como te dije edita mejora tu pregunta y mueve la respuesta a la zona de abajo

Comment: @alfap ya edite la publicación

Answer (score 1):

comparto un Script escrito en VBS (Visual Basic Script), este script lo que realiza es una consulta de los usuarios conectados y desconectados en Windows server, luego el script elimina los espacios separando por un @ y luego realiza un filtrado del arreglo lista buscando los usuarios Desconectados y extrae el id de la sesión para aplicarles el comando CMD: logoff id;

Ojo solo cierra la sesiones de los usuarios Desconectados.

Este script ha sido probado en un servidor de windows para cerrar las sesiones de los usuarios desconectados cada 30 minutos. ha sido configurado con zcron para esta tarea.

Este script lo pueden configurar con el programador de tareas para que se ejecute en determinado tiempo o con ZCron

pueden leer el código no lo copien porque esta comentado con REM y les saldrá error:

```
Set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")
cmd = "query user "
Set resultadoCMD = objshell.exec(cmd)
cadena = resultadoCMD.stdout.readall
msgbox(cadena)
mensaje = ""
palabra = ""
entrar = false
comaAdd = false
fila = 0
columna = 0
Dim lista(100,8) REM LAS COLUMNAS SON FIJAS EN 8 Y EL 100 SIGNIFICA LA CANTIDAD DE FILAS QUE TENDRA EL ARREGLO EN ESTE CASO SERA DE 100 PARA UN LIMITE DE 100 USUARIOS USTED PUEDE MODIFICAR LA CANTIDAD DE USUARIOS DE PENDIENDO DE LA NECESIDAD

REM CLICLO FOR QUE REMPLAZA LOS ESPACIOS POR UN @
for i=0 to Len(cadena) step 1

    caracter = Mid(cadena,(i+1),1)

    if entrar = true then
        if caracter = " " then
            if comaAdd = false then
                mensaje = mensaje + "@"
                comaAdd = true
            end if
        else
            comaAdd = false
            mensaje = mensaje + caracter
        end if

    end if

    if caracter = ">" then
        entrar = true
    end if

    if caracter = "\n" then        
        columna = 0
    end if
next
msgbox(mensaje)

REM CICLO FOR PARA AÑADIR LOS DATOS DE LOS USUARIOS ACTIVOS Y DESCONECTADOS AL ARREGLO LISTA
for i=0 to Len(mensaje) step 1

    caracter = Mid(mensaje,(i+1),1)

    if entrar = true then
        if caracter = "@" then
            lista(fila,columna) = palabra
            palabra = ""
            columna = columna + 1
        else
            palabra = palabra + caracter
        end if
        mensaje = mensaje + caracter
    end if

    if caracter = chr(10) then
        fila = fila + 1
        columna = 0
    end if
next

REM CICLO FOR QUE RECORRE EL ARREGLO LISTA BUSCANDO LOS USUARIOS DESCONECTADOS PARA CERRAR LA SESION
for i=0 to 100 step 1 REM CANTIDAD DE USUARIOS 100
    if lista(i,0) <> "" then
        if lista(i,3) = "Desc" then REM FILTRA POR Desc (Desconectados)
            REM msgbox("Nombre: "+lista(i,0))
            REM msgbox("ID: " + lista(i,2))
            REM msgbox("Estado: " + lista(i,3))
            objshell.exec("logoff " + lista(i,2)) REM CIERRA LA SESION DEL USUARIO LIBERANDO RECURSOS Y LICENCIAS DE ALGUN SOFTWARE QUE ESTE UTILIZANDO
        end if
    end if
next
```

Este es el código original pueden copiar y ejecutar en un ambiente de pruebas (Recuerde comentar los msgbox()):

```
Set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")
cmd = "query user "
Set resultadoCMD = objshell.exec(cmd)
cadena = resultadoCMD.stdout.readall
msgbox(cadena)
mensaje = ""
palabra = ""
entrar = false
comaAdd = false
fila = 0
columna = 0
Dim lista(100,8) ' LAS COLUMNAS SON FIJAS EN 8 Y EL 100 SIGNIFICA LA CANTIDAD DE FILAS QUE TENDRA EL ARREGLO EN ESTE CASO SERA DE 100 PARA UN LIMITE DE 100 USUARIOS USTED PUEDE MODIFICAR LA CANTIDAD DE USUARIOS DE PENDIENDO DE LA NECESIDAD

'CLICLO FOR QUE REMPLAZA LOS ESPACIOS POR UN @
for i=0 to Len(cadena) step 1

    caracter = Mid(cadena,(i+1),1)

    if entrar = true then
        if caracter = " " then
            if comaAdd = false then
                mensaje = mensaje + "@"
                comaAdd = true
            end if
        else
            comaAdd = false
            mensaje = mensaje + caracter
        end if

    end if

    if caracter = ">" then
        entrar = true
    end if

    if caracter = "\n" then        
        columna = 0
    end if
next
msgbox(mensaje)

'CICLO FOR PARA AÑADIR LOS DATOS DE LOS USUARIOS ACTIVOS Y DESCONECTADOS AL ARREGLO LISTA
for i=0 to Len(mensaje) step 1

    caracter = Mid(mensaje,(i+1),1)

    if entrar = true then
        if caracter = "@" then
            lista(fila,columna) = palabra
            palabra = ""
            columna = columna + 1
        else
            palabra = palabra + caracter
        end if
        mensaje = mensaje + caracter
    end if

    if caracter = chr(10) then
        fila = fila + 1
        columna = 0
    end if
next

'CICLO FOR QUE RECORRE EL ARREGLO LISTA BUSCANDO LOS USUARIOS DESCONECTADOS PARA CERRAR LA SESION
for i=0 to 100 step 1 ' CANTIDAD DE USUARIOS 100
    if lista(i,0) <> "" then
        if lista(i,3) = "Desc" then ' FILTRA POR Desc (Desconectados)
            ' msgbox("Nombre: "+lista(i,0))
            ' msgbox("ID: " + lista(i,2))
            ' msgbox("Estado: " + lista(i,3))
            objshell.exec("logoff " + lista(i,2)) ' CIERRA LA SESION DEL USUARIO LIBERANDO RECURSOS Y LICENCIAS DE ALGUN SOFTWARE QUE ESTE UTILIZANDO
        end if
    end if
next
```

Éxitos.